# Split List into multiple lists of similar values C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, count

I have a parent list something like so :-

```
ParentList  = {a,b,c,a,c,d,b,a,c,c}
```

I want to split this list into smaller list something like :-

```
ListA = {a,a,a} ListB = {b,b} ListC= {c,c,c,c} ListD = {d}
```

My main intention is to get the count of the highest occurring value. In the case above it would be `4` which is the count of `ListC`.

How can I split the parent list into small list like stated in example. Or is there a way I can get the greatest count without the list splitting.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Linq GroupBy?

Comment: @GiladGreen I have tried looping through the parent list and creating different lists. But that looks kinda messy. Also, I am not very familier with Linq

Comment: Then please post what you have tried.. Otherwise it just looks like a "write my code for me" question

Comment: LINQ can achieve this in a line, assuming the data type is either string or char: `var highestCount = ParentList.GroupBy(p => p).Max(p => p.Count())` which will only give the highest count (assuming that's all you want)

Comment: @GiladGreen I know I jumped the gun by simply "giving" code to OP, sadly my itchy fingers can't help it when LINQ is involved :|

Comment: @KeyurPATEL Thank you. This was what I needed. If you could post an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you just want the count, and not which character/string gives that count, here is a one liner (you'll need `using System.Linq;`)

```
var highestCount = ParentList.GroupBy(p => p).Max(p => p.Count());
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `GroupBy` to group similar values and then count the amount of items in each group:

```
var result = ParentList.GroupBy(item => item)
                       .Select(group => new {
                           Key = group.Key,
                           Count = group.Count() })
                       .OrderByDescending(item => item.Count);
```

You can also use query syntax:

```
var result = from item in ParentList
             group 1 by item into g
             order by g.Count() descending
             select new { Key = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

If you really want different collections with different variables to them, as in your description above then you need to retrieve from the snippet each collection. You can also use `ToDictionary` on the result of the grouping.

Answer (score 0):

```
string maxRepeated = ParentList.GroupBy(s => s)
                     .OrderByDescending(s => s.Count())
                     .First().Key;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this would be using LINQ

```
var chars = new[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c' };
var largetstGroup = chars
    .GroupBy(_ => _) // Group items by the letter this will yield groups (aka lists) that will conatin only each letter
    .OrderByDescending(_ => _.Count()) //Order by the items in each list
    .FirstOrDefault(); // get the first one
```

If you have more complex objects in your list, where the GroupBy method is used you can specify any property to perform the grouping by (ex, for a list of Persons you could group by age `GroupBy(_=> _.Age)`